# Android - Compare Time String to Current Time Subtract Difference and Convert To MilliSeconds

Tags: android, time

I'm a bit new to Java/Android development and I need to compare two times.  One of the time values is stored in a string and the other is the current to the system time (long) - how can I find out the difference between the two times in milliseconds and store it as a number?

EDIT:

Attempt # 1 (In Response to Lazy Ninja)

```
public class Rules extends Activity {

private String password;

private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
String TIMELIMIT = "10";

TextView textSsid, textSpeed, textRssi, Time;
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1337;
private int count = 0;
private NotificationManager notifyMgr = null;
public Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public long mStartRX = 0;
public long mStartTX = 0;
public long txBytes;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rules);

    String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
    String code = prefs.getString("corename", "");
    String time = prefs.getString("time", "");
    String ssid = prefs.getString("restricted", "");
    Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
    Time.setText(time);

     String dtStart = "09:27:37";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Long convertedLong = date.getTimeInMillis();

    long currentTimeLong = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long difference = currentTimeLong - convertedLong;
     String strDiff = String.valueOf(difference);
```

PROBLEMS:

date cannot be resolved Rules.java  Java Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok convert your string to datetime:

```
String dtStart = "09:27:37";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
 } catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Then convert it to millisec

```
long convertedLong = date.getTimeInMillis();
```

then

```
long currentTimeLong = System.currentTimeMillis(); // will get you current time in milli
long difference = currentTimeLong - convertedLong;
 String strDiff = String.valueOf(difference);
```

From there mathematics currentTimeLong - convertedLong.

Comment: Long.parseLong(time) will do it? (Something tells me there has to be more to it than that to get the difference between the current system time and my time string value then convert it to milliseconds.

Comment: My string is not in milliseconds - it is in standard format (ex 11:00) and I was not able to find a method to do this on google - or S.O.
therefore I posted it as a new question! : )

Comment: @JamesLaur System.currentTimeMillis() is in milliseconds right? That's why I said I assume the string is in milliseconds.

Comment: No my string "time" is in standard format - I was referring to my string - the one I want to compare to the system time

Comment: Actually - I'm still having a bit of trouble setting things up - can you take a look? (I updated my source code above - still having a few small issues related to the source you provided earlier [I'm not sure how/where I should declare the variables you provided in order for the to populate with the correct data])

Comment: See my edit please. First you have to define the variables long, and perform the difference before converting to String.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! For some odd reason it seems as if the 2nd time date is mentioned it doesn't recognize the 1st (or at least I think thats what happening) I'm getting "date cannot be resolved" in the (updated) source above